# Two recoil react tests conflicting based off of rendered value

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router, react-testing-library, recoiljs

I have a single atom that stores an object with `authToken` and `username` strings.  If `authToken` is present, I want to present protected content.  If not, I want to redirect the user to the login page.

Tests:

1. Does not populate the "authToken" and we expect login content in the rendered result.
2. Populates "authToken" and I expect protected content in the rendered result.

When executed in order 2, 1 they are successful. When executed in order 1,2 they fail.

I wonder if there is something that I am missing or is this a known issue.  Any help will be appreciated.

*atom*

```js
import { atom } from 'recoil';

type AuthDetail = {
  authToken?: string;
  userName?: string;
};

const authStateAtom = atom<AuthDetail>({
  key: 'auth-state',
  default: {},
});

export { authStateAtom };
export type { AuthDetail };
```

*PrivateRoute*

```jsx
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { authStateAtom } from './atom';
import { Redirect, Route, RouteProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useRecoilValue } from 'recoil';

const PrivateRoute: FC<RouteProps> = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const authState = useRecoilValue(authStateAtom);

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        authState.authToken ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: { from: location },
            }}
          />
        )}
    />
  );
}

export { PrivateRoute };
```

*Tests*

```jsx
import { act, render, RenderResult } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MutableSnapshot, RecoilRoot } from 'recoil';
import { authStateAtom } from './atom';
import { PrivateRoute } from './PrivateRoute';

describe('PrivateRoute:', () => {
  const protectedComponent = 'protected-component';
  const loginComponent = 'login-component';

  it('redirects to login if not authenticated', async () => {
    let result: RenderResult;
    await act(async () => {
      result = render(
        <RecoilRoot>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact={true} path="/login">
              <div data-testid={loginComponent}>LOGIN COMPONENT</div>
            </Route>
            <PrivateRoute path="/">
              <div data-testid={protectedComponent}>PROTECTED COMPONENT</div>
            </PrivateRoute>
          </Switch>
        </RecoilRoot>,
        { wrapper: HashRouter },
      )
    });

    // @ts-ignore
    expect(result.getByTestId(loginComponent)).toBeInTheDocument();
    // @ts-ignore
    expect(result.queryByTestId(protectedComponent)).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });


  it('renders the component if authenticated', async () => {
    const initialRecoilState = (snap: MutableSnapshot) => {
      snap.set(authStateAtom, { authToken: '1234' });
    };
    let result: RenderResult;
    await act(async () => {
      result = render(
        <RecoilRoot initializeState={initialRecoilState}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact={true} path="/login">
              <div data-testid={loginComponent}>LOGIN COMPONENT</div>
            </Route>
            <PrivateRoute path="/">
              <div data-testid={protectedComponent}>PROTECTED COMPONENT</div>
            </PrivateRoute>
          </Switch>
        </RecoilRoot>,
        { wrapper: HashRouter },
      );
    });

    // @ts-ignore
    expect(await result.findByTestId(protectedComponent)).toBeInTheDocument();
    // @ts-ignore
    expect(result.queryByTestId(loginComponent)).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });


});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-shamir-27s35?file=/src/PrivateRoute.test.tsx

Comment: Hmh... this is weird. Can you by any chance create a reproducible codesandbox?

Comment: Sure, here it is. Switch the test execution sequence around and it will pass. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-shamir-27s35?file=/src/PrivateRoute.test.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are testing with a `<Router>`, `window.history` in your environment can be polluted. If you only run one of your tests, the other one will pass. But when you run them together, your first test will set the URL to `"/login"`. You begin will that URL in your second test.

According to [react-router's testing guide](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/testing), you should wrap your components with `<MemoryRouter>` to protect the global environment.

Here's codesandbox link with both tests passing: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-rhodes-xxuwk?file=/src/PrivateRoute.test.tsx

Comment: Wow! I hadn't thought the history could be the problem.  Thank you for the insightful response!